# CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I'm working with `Telerik Grid` and I want to have a column using the `Template` to acces to other accion. The code I have in the `Grid` is :

```
columnas.Template(o => 
{
    %>
       <%=Html.ActionLink("Texto","Prueba","Peticion", new { id= o.PeticionID }) %>
    <%
}).Title("Prueba");
```

When I run the application I get the error:

> CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

And it show the `{` character after `o =>`

Any idea about what I'm missing?

Comment: My bad advice got an upvote! There is no problem spliting lambdas across server tags.

Answer (score 4):

From the point of view of the C# code (not including server tags), the lambda expression in columnas.Template is empty... which will result in an error.

effectively what you've written is this:

```
columnas.Template(o => { }).Title("Prueba");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to track down the answer.

From http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/invalid-expression-term-in-template-statement.aspx

Basically, if you are using column Templates then your grid code should be:

```
<% Html.Telerik.Grid()
-
-
.Render();%>
```

instead of:

```
<%= Html.Telerik.Grid()
-
-
%>
```

It's hidden fairly well in here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good chance you have an extra ) somewhere at the end of the `Grid` method.